# Is there a way to mount or expose a folder within a package to another folder?

Tags: photos

I'm trying to create a time-lapse video from jpegs using GoPro studio on the MAC but that (and alternatives I've tried) don't seem to understand how to access all the photos in the Photos app.

If I right-click on the Photos app and go to 'show package' contents, I can see all my photos in a directory called 'Masters'.

Is there any way to mount or otherwise expose that folder as a standard folder that other applications might be able to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an alias outside the bundle to expose this folder (by command-option dragging "Masters" out of the bundle). However, it is not always advisable to mess with the contents of a bundle, so proceed with caution. If you're just *reading* the photos, there's no problem, but Photos may not take kindly to modifications. The "safest" (but most annoying) way to access items in your Photos library is to export them from Photos itself.

Comment: If this is a temporary situation one could copy the Masters directory from the bundle, so Photos won't be seeing any modifications that may occur.  If it's an ongoing need, a guy could set up an automated task to sync the Masters directory out to some accessible location.  It's brute force, but also the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work.

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Just needed read access and didn't want to duplicate several gigs of data!

Answer (score 0):

If the application you are using has a standard file selection dialog (the kind that Apple uses), you can drag and drop a folder or files from the Finder into that dialog.

In your case, this means you could open the package in the Finder and simply drag the “Masters” folder into the GoPro “Open” dialog.